# How do I make the choices in radioButtons reactive in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

This is what I have and I think the problem is that the ui.R runs first, so the function progs() isn't defined (or I don't know how to do reactive functions). My error looks like this:

> Error in lapply(obj, function(val) { : could not find function "progs"

and my code looks like this:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
progs <- list.files("C:/Users/OIT-Classroom/Desktop/ODP/Report 1/aggregate/")
progs <- gsub('.{6}$', '', progs)

shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  tabsetPanel(id="Reports",
              tabPanel("Report 1",
                       sidebarPanel(
                         p("text"),
                         radioButtons("choices", choices = progs(), label = "Programs")
                      ),
                       mainPanel(
                         tableOutput('age')
                       )
              ),
              tabPanel("Report 2",
                       sidebarPanel(
                         p("text"),
                         radioButtons("choices", choices = progs(), label = "Programs")
                       ),
                       mainPanel(
                         tableOutput('psc5'),
                         plotOutput('psc5p'),
                       )
              ) 
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  progs <- reactive({
    progs <- list.files(paste("C:/Users/OIT-Classroom/Desktop/ODP/", input$Reports, "/aggregate/", input$choices, ".RData", sep = ""))
    gsub('.{6}$', '', progs)
  })

  output$age <- function(){
    paste(knitr::kable(
      age, format = 'html', output = FALSE,
      table.attr="class='data table table-bordered table-condensed'"),
      sep = '\n')
  }
  output$psc5 <- function(){
    paste(knitr::kable(
      psc5, format = 'html', output = FALSE,
      table.attr="class='data table table-bordered table-condensed'"),
      sep = '\n')
  }
  output$psc5p <- renderPlot({
    plot(psc5[, 2:3], type="b", ylim=c(0, 40), ylab="", xaxt="no", xlab="", col="red", main="Figure 2: Problem Severity Comparison of Mean Scores for Children Ages 5+", cex.main=0.8, cex.axis = 0.8, font.main = 1, family="serif")
    par(new = T)
    axis(1, at=1:2, labels=c("Intake", "Discharge"), col.axis="black", las=1, cex.axis =0.8)
  })
})
```

Comment: Put them in the Server.R file or you can add them to a global.R file or even another file you can source in the server and ui.  http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

Comment: Try adding return(progs) at the end of progs reactive.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're trying to automatically update the choices for the radio buttons. The `progs` function you are trying to call isn't defined in the UI script so that's where your error is coming from. Try using the `observe` and `updateRadioButtons` functions somewhere in your server script. Might look something like this:

```
observe({
  updateRadioButtons(session, "choices", choices = progs())
})
```

If you then go into your UI script and change the `progs()` part of the radio buttons definition to just `progs` it should work off the `progs` variable you defined at the beginning of the UI. I can't test all of this, since I don't have the files, but it should get you close.