# Update two sets of radiobuttons - shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I asked this question ([Update two sets of radiobuttons reactively - shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040579/update-two-sets-of-radiobuttons-reactively-shiny)) yesterday but perhaps it was too messy to get a response. I have stripped the question down: why can't I get two sets of radiobuttons to update reactively:

server.R:

```
# Create example data

Wafer <- rep(c(1:3), each=3)
Length <- c(1,1,2,1,1,1,3,5,1)
Width <- c(3,1,6,1,1,1,1,1,6)

dd <- data.frame(Wafer, Length, Width)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

# Get Lengths from user input   
 a <- eventReactive(input$do, {
       subset(dd, Wafer %in% input$wafer, select = Length) 
 })

# Get Widths from user input   
 b <- eventReactive(input$do, {
   subset(dd, Wafer %in% input$wafer, select = Width) 
 })

#Observe and update first set of radiobuttons based on a(). Does
#render   
  observe({ 
    z <- a()
    updateRadioButtons(session, "length", choices = unique(z$Length), inline=TRUE)
  })

#Observe and update second set of radiobuttons based on b(). Does 
#not render     
  observe({ 
    z <- b()
    updateRadioButtons(session, "width", choices = unique(z$Width), inline=TRUE)
  })

  output$l <- renderDataTable({ a() })
  output$w <- renderDataTable({ b() })  
})
```

ui.R:

```
library(markdown)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Generic grapher"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      numericInput("wafer", label = h3("Input wafer ID:"), value = NULL),

      actionButton("do", "Search wafer"),
      radioButtons("length", label="Length", choices=""),
      radioButtons("width", label="Width", choices = "")

    ),

    mainPanel(

      dataTableOutput(outputId="l"),
      dataTableOutput(outputId="w")

    )))
)
```

In the above, I can only get one set of radiobuttons to reactive ("Length"). However, if I comment out the Length `observe`, the Width one works so my code must be OK in isolation. Maybe I'm missing something simple?

Comment: Ok, so if I change one set of radiobuttons to be a selectInput and change the corresponding updateRadioButtons to updateSelectInput then it works. I can use that but would prefer two sets of radiobuttons if anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could be a bug, I changed the order of the `updateRadioButtons` and only the first one works...

Comment: Thanks NicE. Is there anything I can do? Perhaps post of the RStudio page or git or something? I've never had to do something like that so not sure of the correct etiquette.

Comment: Actually I tested it with some other code and having two `updateRadioButtons` works so maybe it's something else.

Comment: I think it is linked to the actionButton. If I split it so there are two actionbuttons, one for each set of radiobuttons then it works. Can you send me your code where you tried two updateRadioButtons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a bug of the `updateRadioButtons` function. When `selected` is not set, it is replaced by the first choice. I guess this causes an error if the choices list is numeric.

To fix your problem, you can either convert your choices to characters using `as.character` or set `selected` to a random string such as `""`.

Using `as.character` is probably better as you then get your first selection automatically selected.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for figuring this out. Is it my duty of any sorts to point the potential bug out to somebody?

Comment: Yeah you can raise an issue in the shiny github https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues. I changed my answer a bit, turns out there's an issue when the choices is numeric and not character.